# Null Exception when using .ToList().ForEach() in C#

Tags: c#, list

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to parse some data and writing statements like the below one to remove unwanted contents -

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul").ToList().ForEach(a => a.Remove());
```

This works well when there's `<ul>` element present in the HTML document. However, if there's no `<ul>` element, I get a **Value cannot by null** exception when converting it into .ToList().

I do not want to use the following -

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul")== null ? null : doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul").ToList().ForEach(a => a.Remove());
```

What elegant alternatives do I have?

Comment: What do you find *inelegant* about your proposed solution? (Except, of course, that it wont compile! - `ForEach` is void and `null` on the other side won't coalesce)

Comment: @Jamiec, I know it won't compile and just wanted to share the way I don't want to write. This approach is OK when using on a single tag, but let's say I have around 100 tags and I want to remove them. lot of code to be written and I know I can transfer this into a function but that does not server the function properly as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example you are calling `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul")` twice. What is wrong with

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul");
if(nodes != null)
   nodes.ToList().ForEach(a => a.Remove());
```

Comment: Is remove within a foreach really recommended?

Comment: @Thomas it's what the OP is doing, and isn't what the question is about.

Comment: @Marius, I was wondering if this can be written in single statement. Please advise.

Comment: @Thomas, why is it nor recommended? Any links?

Comment: It can be in C# 6. But a statement should not be your goal. Your goal should be correct and simple code.

Comment: Well I have [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/832183/2307070) right now, more to come after @Nitesh

Comment: @Thomas, I would wait for another link from you :)

Answer (score 4):

If you have C# 6 available you can use The [`Null Conditional Operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx):

`doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul")?.ToList().ForEach(a => a.Remove());`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `RemoveAll` instead of a ForEach (if you can use C#6):

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul")?.ToList().RemoveAll();
```

Or

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul");
if(nodes != null)
    nodes.ToList().RemoveAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `null` condition.

```
var docNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul");
if(docNodes != null)
   docNodes .ToList().ForEach(a => a.Remove());
```